# Dar salto de línea luego de cierto ancho con la etiqueta <pre>

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando mostrar un texto respetando todos los espacios que contenga el mismo texto, para eso estoy usando la etiqueta `<pre>`. Tengo un problema con eso, ya que me gustaría que después de cierto ancho, el texto se vaya hacia abajo, ejemplo: si tengo un texto que con el `<pre>` se ve así:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tempor efficitur elit, eget finibus nulla tempus a. Mauris non libero blandit, ultricies lacus eget, iaculis tortor. Mauris sit amet odio a odio rutrum ornare.
```

A mí me gustaría mostrarlo así:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tempor efficitur 
elit, eget finibus nulla tempus a. Mauris non libero blandit, ultricies lacus eget, 
iaculis tortor. Mauris sit amet odio a odio rutrum ornare.
```

Como pueden ver, en el primer ejemplo el texto se puede ver si te mueves a la derecha, pero en el segundo ejemplo el texto está abajo, entonces ¿hay una forma de hacer que el `pre` siga respetando los espacios pero que después de cierto ancho el texto se baje? Busqué un poco en internet pero no encontré una respuesta que me ayudara.

Por cierto, este es mi código html, es demasiado simple:

```html
<pre>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras lacinia lectus enim, eget ornare nulla malesuada quis. Cras ullamcorper porttitor nibh, sed hendrerit turpis hendrerit eget. Sed a metus rhoncus, blandit elit eget, condimentum justo. Nulla facilisi. Fusce consectetur fringilla arcu, in placerat tortor luctus eget. Duis quam neque, suscipit ornare aliquam sed, pharetra sit amet nibh. Nam gravida odio ac nibh varius, quis ultrices ex pellentesque. Pellentesque suscipit pulvinar mauris eget commodo. Etiam venenatis viverra urna ut pellentesque. Praesent vitae ultricies erat.
</pre>
```

Comment: Por qué estás usando un pre y no un p?

Comment: @LuisS.Romero porque creo que el pre lo que hace es respetar los espacios del texto que el mismo contenga, el p no estoy seguro de si lo hace o no

Comment: El pre efectivamente respeta algunos aspectos como el cómo está escrito el texto y sus espacios, pero hay o habrá más de un espacio entre caracteres en alguna parte del texto? El P ya te ajusta el texto, el pre si lo escribes a lo largo lo mostrará a lo largo..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para resolver eso en una etiqueta pre, lo que debes hacer es agregar lo siguiente en css:

```
pre {
   border: 1px solid green;
   white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
   white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
   word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

El white-space, justamente define como se comportan los espacios, pre-wrap mantiene espacios, tabulaciones, agrega saltos de linea y ajusta el texto.. El word-wrap: break-word, agrega saltos de linea entre palabras cuando es necesario, para ajustar el texto al tamaño deseado. Notaras que sin ser el primero, todos tienen comentarios, estas otras propiedades son para compatibilidad con diferentes navegadores y versiones.

Comment: El white-space, justamente define como se comportan los espacios, pre-wrap mantiene espacios, tabulaciones,  agrega saltos de linea y ajusta el texto.. El word-wrap: break-word, agrega saltos de linea entre palabras cuando es necesario, para ajustar el texto al tamaño deseado. Notaras que sin ser el primero, todos tienen comentarios, estas otras propiedades son para compatibilidad con diferentes navegadores y versiones.

Comment: supongo que, ¿ eso también es posible con p?

Comment: a que parte te refieres específicamente?

Answer (score 1):

```
Bueno segun entiendo lo que quieres es un salto de linea al final de la etiqueta </ pre > intenta usar la etiqueta < br >
< pre style="text-align:justify">lorem< br >
lorem < br >
lorem < br >
</ pre >
puedes justificar tu texto para que alcance los extremos del contenedor div y luego donde necesites un salto congruete utilizar la etiqueta < br >
```

Comment: si lo pruebas en un html justifico el texto y donde necesito un salto congruente agrego un <br> dentro de el <em> y el resultado es un salto de linea y un texto limpio

Comment: te he editado la respuesta de la forma en la que he manejado esta duda, espero haberte ayudado amigo